# Getting and Using Input HTML Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm relatively new to coding and I'm trying to get number values from an HTML number input and then use that value in JavaScript.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Phone Price Calculator</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/phonePrice.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <p>How much money is in your bank account?</p><p>$ <input type="number" id="money" placeholder="ex. 9250.00"></input></p>
        <p>How much are you willing to spend on a new phone?</p><p>$ <input type="number" id="newPhone" placeholder="ex. 130.00"></input></p>
        <button type="button" id="spendButton">Spend Money!</button>
        <p>Tax is 8.25%</p>
        <hr>
        <p id="total">Total: </p>


        <script src="../js/phonePrice.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

--JavaScript--

```
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let money = document.getElementById("money").value;
let newPhone = document.querySelector("#newPhone").value;
let tax = 0.0825;
let total = document.getElementsByName("total");


button.addEventListener("click", function (){
    console.log(money);
    console.log(newPhone);
});
```

Both of my console.log statements return an empty string.  I want to be able to set the variables to whatever input the user sets and then use those values (numbers) in my functions.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign values to `money` and `newPhone` **when the script is loaded**.

Then the user types something into the fields (which changes the values in the fields, but not in the variables) and clicks the button (which is when you use the values you collected earlier).

Collect the values *when the button is clicked* instead of when the script is loaded.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!  It worked!   I moved my variables inside of my function and my console.log statements return the given input.  These are numbers or technically strings?

Comment: Values of form controls are always strings.

Comment: Ok thank you again for your help!  I will throw Number() or parseInt() on those values then :D